# Неравенство второй степени

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно представить решение неравенства второй степени на языке С++, чтобы после нахождения корней квадратного уравнения x1 и x2 выводились промежутки, то есть, чтобы ответ в конце выводился в виде интервалов.

Программный код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> 
#include <conio.h>
#include "windows.h" 
using namespace std;

int main()
{  
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    SetConsoleTitle (L"Неравенство второй степени");
    cout << "Введите коэффициенты\n"; //выводим сообщение 
    double a, b, c; //назначаем целые числа 
    cout << "a = "; //форма ввода   
    cin >> a; 
    cout << "b = "; 
    cin >> b;

    cout << "c = "; 
    cin >> c; 
    double d = b * b - 4 * a * c; //Дискриминант d вычисляется по формуле   
    if ( d < 0 ) //если d меньше нуля, то сообщение; 
    { 
        cout << "Дискриминант меньше нуля\n"; 
        system("pause"); //задержка, пауза в окне программы 
        return 0; 
    };

    double x1, x2;
    x1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2.0 * a); //Выводим значения корней уравнения 
    x2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2.0 * a);  
    cout << "x1 = " << x1 << "\n"; 
    cout << "x2 = " << x2 << "\n"; 
    system("pause"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: А в чём, собственно, проблема? Зная корни, выводите интервалы в зависимости от знака неравенства. Что конкретно вы сделали и что не получилось?

Comment: Вот смотрите, написал программный код для решения квадратного уравнения и дальше не понятно как выводить ответ в виде интервалов

Comment: Это же неравенство, где вводится его знак?
(меньше/больше/меньше-равно/больше-равно нуля)
И отформатируйте код в вопросе, нечитабельно ведь.

Comment: в начале нам нужно ввести формулу такую ax^2+bx+c>=0?

Comment: Подскажите,пожалуйста, что там не так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После ввода коэффициентов домножьте всё на -1, если a < 0, и поменяйте знак неравенства. Затем, если знак >=, интервал будет "по бокам" от корней, иначе "внутри" между корнями.

Comment: Домножить на -1 нужно в дискриминанте?

Comment: Нет, сразу после считывания проверяете, если а < 0, домножаете a, b и с на -1 и меняете знак на противоположный.

А если дискриминант < 0, то в зависимости от знака неравенства (если >=), будет х є R, иначе (если <=) не будет решений.

Comment: А как это в коде записать?

Comment: По правилам ресурса я не могу решить вам задачу полностью, могу лишь указать на решение, что я уже сделал. Попробуйте разобраться сами, это несложно.